# Duvida na implementacao de juncao para jogo da velha

Tags: c

Ola sou nova em programação e estou tentando entender um código. Minha duvida esta mais na parte de imprimir o conteúdo do vetor, o pq foi usado dois %c no comando print, deixei sublinhado a parte que estou com duvida.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DIM 3

void mostra(char v[][DIM])
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=0;i<DIM; i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<DIM;j++)
        {
            printf(**"%c %c",v[i][j],j==DIM-1**?' ': '|');
        }
        if(i!=DIM-1)
        {
            printf("\n----------");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Tem dois %c porque o printf vai imprimir dois caracteres (o %c significa que no lugar dele vai aparecer um caractere)

j==DIM-1?' ': '|'

Essa parte significa que se j for igual a DIM-1 um espaço em branco vai ser impresso, caso não seja igual o que vai ser impresso vai ser o símbolo |
Resumindo o primeiro %c mostra o conteúdo da variável v e o segundo %c imprime ou um espaço em branco ou o símbolo|.

Answer (score -3):

O %c é usado na linguagem C para indicar o local de armazenamento de um caractere do tipo char (%s seria no caso de uma string inteira).Nesse trecho que você colocou em negrito, dois caracteres serão impressos, sendo que um deles está sendo condicionado pelo operador ternário (ponto de interrogação) que funciona dessa maneira : **Condição ? verdadeiro : falso**
No caso da condição ser verdadeira,imprime o caractere nulo, se for falso imprime a |. Espero ter ajudado, se ainda ficou com dúvida avisa.